# Affect javascript value to c# variable

Tags: javascript, c#, variables, transpose

In my ASP code (Webforms) I would like to retrieve and affect to a c# variable a value obtained through javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ratebeer.com/javascript/sc.asp?b=53"></script>
```

The value "53" in the script can be changed by the user in an ASP form that I've already created so that we can dynamically obtain the score of the desired product.

Can you please tell me how I can provide the value typed by the user to the script and affect the returned value to a c# variable?

Many thanks in advance

Solution to display the returned value:

```
<script type="text/javascript" style="color: yellow !important" src="http://www.ratebeer.com/javascript/sc.asp?b=<%#: Item.RateBeerNumber  %>"></script>
```

Comment: What server side framework are you using? ASP.NET WebForms? MVC? Classic ASP?

Comment: Great, please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following thing in ASP.NET WebForms

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://www.ratebeer.com/javascript/sc.asp?b=<% Response.Write("53");  %>"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe I havent been clear enough.
This script is provided by RateBeer to dynamically get the score of the products. 53 in this case is just an example and is the reference of only one product. I want the user of my website to insert a reference number of a product in a form and use it to get the score associated to it.

Comment: You can replace `"53"` with any variable, that part is standard C# code.

Comment: Ok great this works good now but I still dont know how to affect the returned value to a C# variable in order to stock it in the database.

Comment: If it answered your question, mark it as answered. If you want to put data in a database, just go ahead and do it in your code behind. You can use the same variable for that.

Comment: I don't want to stock 53 but the value returned by the script!

Comment: As I said, this is standard C#. Do whatever you want in the `Response.Write`. `sp?b=<% Response.Write(Session["UserData"]);  %>"`

Comment: Test this script. With the value 53 it will return 100. This value is obtained on client side for the moment. I want a solution for this script to be executed on the server side and record the 100 in the database each time a user will use my form.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit it and explain with more details what you want to happen and what's preventing you from doing that.